# How to save only change data in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid, rows

I'm using [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/).

When the user execute (add/change/delete) rows more than often, and some documents have hundreds of rows.

If a user clicks the Save button, all rows (including no changed rows) are updated at once and it takes a while when rows are in the hundreds.

I just want to update the changed data only.

Is there any row status check function?

Comment: I suppose that you use form editing. You can use `reloadAfterSubmit: false` [property](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) of form editing to prevent reloading of the grid. Moreover you should consider to use small page size (small value of `rowNum`) to improve the performance. If the total number of rows is not so large (less as 1000 or less as 10000) then you can consider to use `loadonce: true` scenario. It can improve the performance essentially. In any way you should post JavaScript code and write which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork.

Answer (score 0):

To verify whether the data has been changed or not during editing you can use the internal `jqGrid` option `savedRow`:

`var row = $("#yourGrid").getGridParam("savedRow");` to get the data.

According to the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing):

> The array `savedRow` (option in the grid) is filled with the values before the editing. This is a `name:value` pair array with additional pair `id:rowid`
>
> After the row is saved or restored the editable attribute is set to `“0”` and the `savedRow` item with `id=rowid` is deleted